# CMake target_include_directories: Do I use PUBLIC, PRIVATE or INTERFACE?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMake-library `add_library(helpers helpers.h)` and I want to include the source files via `target_include_directories`. Then I have to choose between the parameters `PRIVATE`, `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE`.

What is the difference?

Comment: Closely related, if not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69783203/examples-of-when-public-private-interface-should-be-used-in-cmake

Comment: @fabian True, but I consider this question much clearer and more beginner-friendly.

Comment: @Chris ***add_library(helpers helpers.h)***, what's that? No source code, and merely a header. How can a library only be created by headers? Could you please explain more in details for me?

Comment: @John for example fmt is header-only: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt. Especially templates cannot be defined separately in a *.cpp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. `PRIVATE`: The includes can only be used by the helpers-library itself.
2. `PUBLIC`: The includes can be used by the helpers-library itself and any target that uses the helpers-library, e.g. via `target_link_libraries(MainApplication PUBLIC libhelpers)`.
3. `INTERFACE`: The includes can't be used by the helpers-library, only by targets that use  the helpers-library.

This **example** illustrates the possible imports. Structure:

```
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   helper.cpp
│   main.cpp
│
├───details_interface
│       details_interface.cpp
│
├───details_private
│       details_private.cpp
│
└───details_public
        details_public.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project(cmake_experiment)

add_executable(cmake_experiment main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(cmake_experiment libhelper)

add_library(libhelper helper.cpp)

target_include_directories(libhelper
        INTERFACE details_interface
        PUBLIC details_public
        PRIVATE details_private)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "details_public.cpp"
#include "details_interface.cpp"

// fatal error: details_private.cpp: No such file or directory:
// #include "details_private.cpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

helper.cpp:

```
#include "details_public.cpp"
#include "details_private.cpp"

// fatal error: details_interface.cpp: No such file or directory:
// #include "details_interface.cpp"
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can not use INTERFACE for an real library, I think its exclusive for interface libraries.

Comment: @gerum `I am pretty sure that you can not use INTERFACE for an real library, I think its exclusive for interface libraries` I am pretty sure that you can use INTERFACE whenever you want on any library. Have you tested it?

Comment: @gerum Incorrect. `INTERFACE`  visibility any be used for any target. It just makes sense for libraries though and it's pretty rare that there are headers that aren't included in the library itself. (I've just tested this to be sure.)

Comment: @gerum That is not true, I added an example containing ```INTERFACE```

Comment: Beyond abstraction is there any other benefit to hiding included headers behind PRIVATE?

Comment: @rocksNwaves in big projects you might get better build-times. And unnecessary public includes are more error prone.